# Difference Between Eclipse Juno and Eclipse Kepler

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-kepler

What is the difference between *eclipse juno* and *eclipse kepler*, I have done a web project in *juno*. can I import it in to *kepler* ?

Comment: Import should be straight forward. You can copy your workspace and test it using the new version, doing rollback if needed.

Comment: @CedricSimon ok, i'll try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

eclipse kepler and juno differed in their packages.
for checking the packages visit : http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/